# How to make visibility is false for an ASP:Image?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a set of  ASP:Images in my project.When the mouse pointer mouses over a tab then the particular tab's image is shown. Till now its working well by keeping Visibility=true and style.visibility:hidden and on Mouse over event i am keep style.visibility:visible.

image is showing but its location is not in the correct position.I thought its all because of visibility true for remaining images.

can anyone suggest me to make visibility false .or to make images to be shown at particular location.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use style

```
display:none
```

and

```
display:block
```

instead of `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding here, but this seems to be more of a css, javascript question than an asp/c# question. It would also be easier to formulate a useful answer if we had a bit of example code that clarified the question a little bit, but I suggest 2 possible solutions:

1. position these elements with absolute positioning based on the parent containers.
2. Add a visible wrapper div around the elements to keep the position the same.